# Writing a good Reward Function for my QLearning Agent

Tags: python, q-learning

I'm still new to ML, recently I've learned Q-Learning and coded it manually (Not using a library like Keras or TensorFlow), and the problem I'm facing is knowing how to write a good reward function for my agent, I've started by writing the following simple reward function:

When moving from X, Y to X1, Y1:
Return (Distance(from X,Y to Target) - Distance (from X1,Y1 to Target))

Which means it got positive reward whenever it moved towards the Target, and it worked fine on an empty 2D plain.

But when I added obstacles, that function did not help, the agent took the shortest path to the target getting stuck in obstacles forever, I added punishment for staying in place, and it got stuck against the wall again but this time going back and forth because the total of punishment + reward was 0, and it had already gotten a positive reward so this was the favourable path.
I then added punishment for passing the same square twice, but still, I feel like this may have gotten too convoluted, and that there must be a simpler way to do this

Starting position (Green is the agent, Red is the target)
[image]

Getting stuck in the blocked shortest direct path
[image]

I realize there are multiple things I've understood/done wrong about the reward after reading about it a bit, from having my reward go up to 2k in one move, instead of being in the range [-1, 1], and not having a clear distinction of when to use Negative vs Positive reward.

My memory array of state vs action consists of n states where n=rows*columns, and 5 actions (up, right, down, left, stayinplace).

So, knowing that my agent is supposed to find the Shortest **Available** Path to the target (Not blocked), what should my reward function look like? and why?
Also following the algorithm I learned from, they didn't really specify the values for Epsilon, Gamma and LearningRate, so I set them to 0.2, 0.85, 0.75 respectively.

My code is in python if you want to send the reward function in code.

PS: I searched up the problem on and off StackOverflow and all I found was references and articles, all of which explained what a reward function should do, but no detail on how to make it do that, or turn my query into a reward function.

Here's my code file on Github (No GUI): https://github.com/EjHam98/LearningMachineLearning/blob/master/QLearning.py

Comment: Try using: -1 reward form each step (which forces agent to learn shortest path), some more negative reward for hitting obstacles and some positive reward for reaching target

Comment: I tried returning -1 each step, or return -1*n where n is the number of steps so far, and both didn't work, I knew it wouldn't work because I need the shortest **Available** path, which isn't necessarily the shortest distance to the target, as shown in the example in the images, thus punishing a longer route means the agent is discouraged from the correct path because it's longer.
Basically the Agent has to work similarly to backtrack

Comment: "punishing a longer route means the bot is discouraged from the correct path because it's longer" I don't think it is true. -1 reward stops it from repeating same steps and encourages agent to reach target as fast possible. As you are training DQN agent what you are considering  as `observation` also matters a lot check that.

Comment: Better take 2d grid representing environment state as observation. And  stack it with some previous observations to form Agents's state representation. And use CNN as function approximator.

Comment: I'm starting to think My code/understanding is horribly wrong, I've already studied CNN, but while studying Qlearning it had no mention of CNN, here's the link of what I followed with my code: https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-reinforcement-learning-q-learning-fcddc4b6fe56#:~:text=Q%2Dlearning%20is%20an%20off,a%20policy%20isn't%20needed.
is it good? is it enough?

Comment: That means you are implementing Q-learning not DQN. But you mentioned Deep Q-learning in your question so I suggested CNN. If you want to implement it using classical Q-leaning you need very good Agent's state representation which should encode agent's position along with surrounding conditions.

Comment: Yeah sorry it appears I'm confused about the two, I meant Q-learning, and I added a link to my code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219955/discussion-between-lieutenantdv20-and-girish-dattatray-hegde).

Answer (score 0):

In case of your environment state-action space is very large. Considering only just 10 obstacles the total states will be more than `49x48x47c10` which is more than `10e13` here not even actions and other possible number of obstacles are considered.

So it is better to use `Deep Q-learning` with power full `CNN` function aproximator.

- Observation   - 2d grid representing the maze(or image)
- Agent's state - stack of current observation along with some previous frames(2, 3).
- Reward structure

  - -1 for each time step
  - +ve reward for reaching target state
  - -ve reward for hitting obstacles

And better using Q-learning for simple environments(like [OpenAI](https://gym.openai.com/) gym control environments). [Here's](https://github.com/girishdhegde/reinforcement-learning/tree/master) sample implementation of q-learning for `gym` control environment.

Comment: The way I have it set up is:
State: current position as a single integer between 0 and rows*columns-1
(in this case 49 states
Actions are 5 possible actions (up, down, right, left, stay)
so my state-action table is just 49*5
But It's probably wrong since honestly I've doubted everything i know on this topic, also I thought this was a simple environment, it's just 2D with walls, and a single objective..

Can you please provide me on good learning resources for Q-Learning and DQN? and I'd prefer ones that explain the algorithm and its details and how it works in detail

Comment: storing only position won't work because agent needs to consider surroundings before taking action. For eg: In 1st episode there is a obstacle left to position `(3, 3)` but during next episode obstacle can be to the right of `3, 3`. Agent's position won't help to encode such situation. Refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzuuYNsE1EZAXYR4FJ75jcJseBmo4KQ9-) awesome lecture's of David Silver.

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciated! Time for me to properly learn